# What does the '?' mean in the following Python list code?

Tags: python, list, vector

As above, I was looking over an example to drive some work I was doing, and I saw the code for a list below.  Is there a special meaning behind the '?' below?  I know about it acting as a ternary operator, but that isn't obvious here.  This is also not regex. Thanks!

```
inputVector = [1.1, '?']
```

Comment: It's just a string consisting only of `?`. Of course this string could be fed as pattern into a regex function.

Comment: It's just a list object (string)

Comment: Python's ternary operator doesn't use `?` anyway. That's a C-family thing.

Comment: It is just a string.  No different than if you used `inputVector = [1.1, 'question mark']`

Comment: Read too much into it I guess - thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Nope. No special meanings as far as python is concerned. Just a poor string.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a regular string inside list in python.

1.1 = float

'?' = string

I think you are assuming about ternary operator like in other language but there are no such ternary operator in python, in fact we can use equivalent.

Example: [list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list)